# To merge values from different sources in my rxjs BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am using rxjs BehaviorSubject to create a service, upon sending values from Component1 and on subscribing in Component3, I get the values in Component3, this is achieved

## Service file

```
`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

   @Injectable()
   export class UserService {

     constructor() { }

     // Observable navItem source
     public _navItemSource = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

     // Observable navItem stream
     navItem$ = this._navItemSource.asObservable();

     // service command
     changeNav(nu) {
       this._navItemSource.next([...nu]);
     }
  }`
```

## Component1

```
  `this._userService.changeNav(self.notificationslist);`
```

## Component3

```
  `this.subscription = this._userService.navItem$.subscribe(item =>   
   this.item1 = item);`
```

Now I want to use the same service in one more component(Component2) to send some different values to the same component Component3

## Component2

```
 `this._userService.changeNav(this.updatedFlag);`
```

## Component3

```
  `this.subscription = this._userService.navItem$.subscribe(item =>   
   this.item1 = item);`
```

And then upon subscribing it on Component3 I should get all the values from Component1 and Component2.
So I have updated my service file but I get the following error

`caused by: this._navItemSource.asObservable(...).scan is not a function`

Please correct me where I am going wrong as I am new to rxjs.

## Updated Service file

```
`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

 @Injectable()
 export class UserService {

 constructor() {
 }

  // Observable navItem source
  public _navItemSource = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

  // Observable navItem stream
  navItem$ = this._navItemSource.asObservable().scan((acc, one) =>(acc + 
  one));

  // service command
  changeNav(nu) {
    this._navItemSource.next([...nu]);
  }

}`
```

Comment: make sure you import scan operator! import "rxjs/add/operator/scan";

Comment: Thanks alot @JayDeeEss that error has due to scan operator not being imported ,but I am only getting the value of Component1 but not from Component2, I am passing an array from Component1 and a single value from Component2

Comment: your function doesn't look right if one is array and other is single value. You either have to somehow return array from both and merge into one or return a json where first is array and second is single value as scan always going to return one value

Comment: ok I have already defined updatedFlag = [] in Component2, but I thought just for info I'll tell

Comment: ok then you can use concat() to merge 2 arrays if thats what you want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=a

Comment: Sorry to ask it might sound dumb but where should I concat() the arrays, thankyou

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155090/discussion-between-enthu-and-jaydeeess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you import scan operator. and in the scan function to merge your results you can return a JSON with the previous and new value emitted

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fXFZwAPxzBcdCOgf1Rsy?p=preview)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import "rxjs/add/operator/scan";
 @Injectable()
 export class UserService {

 constructor() {
 }

  // Observable navItem source
  public _navItemSource = new BehaviorSubject(Object([]));

  // Observable navItem stream
  navItem$ = this._navItemSource.asObservable().scan((acc, one) => {
                    return {
                        'previous': acc, 'new': one
                    }
                });

  // service command
  changeNav(nu) {
    this._navItemSource.next([...nu]);
  }

}
```